# Exact effect of declaring variable inside if block

Tags: c, scope, icc

I am tying to understand the effect of the following in C:

```
int func(int arg) {
    if (arg == 0) {
        double *d = malloc(...);
    }
    //...
}
```

My understanding is:

- Regardless of the value of `arg`, stack space will be made for the pointer `d` when `func` is invoked
- `d` is only initialised, i.e. `malloc` called, if `arg == 0`
- `d` can only be accessed inside the if block; trying to access it outside will generate a compile error - even though the stack space for `d` is allocated regardless.

So, it is equivalent to the following except for the scoping rules that prevent access outside the if block:

```
int func(int arg) {
    double *d;
    if (arg == 0) {
        d = malloc(...);
    }
    //...
}
```

Is this correct? I am compiling with `icc` default settings which seems to be `std=gnu89`.

Comment: Point one may be incorrect. Probably compiler dependent.

Comment: There doesn't even have to be *any* stack. C does not mandate a stack, and even if a stack is used, the compiler may keep variables in registers instead.

Answer (score 2):

The lifetime of the object denoted by `d` starts at the beginning of the block in which it is declared (which might be prior to the declaration), not necessarily at the beginning of the function. In practice, compilers may choose to allocate space for all variables at function entry; Gcc, for example, compiles both versions of `func` to identical assembly. With only a few automatic variables in a function, it's likely that they are all placed in registers and no stack space is used for them at all.

Initialization happens at the point where the initializer appears. All this is subject to the as-if rule (as always): In this case, Gcc doesn't generate any call to `malloc` when optimizing (and thereby removes the memory leak), a compiler is allowed to "know" what standard library functions do. If this wasn't a library function and the definition not known to the compiler, the call was guaranteed to occur exactly when the initializer is reached.

Using an undeclared identifier (or one that has gone out of scope) is a syntax error, and thus caught at compile-time. The lifetime of the denoted object (with automatic storage duration) ends with the enclosing block, any attempt to refer to it afterwards (through a pointer which used to point to the object) is undefined, no diagnostic required.

In the second code snippet, it's not only syntactically possible to use `d` after the `if` block, it's also defined to access the denoted object.

To illustrate the difference between the scope of an identifier and the lifetime of the denoted object, this is valid C99 (and C11) code:

```
void foo(void) {
    int *p = 0;
again:
    if(p) {
        printf("%d\n", *p); /* n is not in scope here, but the object exists */
        *p = 0;
    }
    int n = 42;
    printf("%d\n", n);
    if(!p) {
        p = &n;
        goto again;
    }
}
```

The output is three times `42`, when the initializer is reached the second time, `n` is re-initialized to 42 (and does not stay 0).

Such questions don't arise for C89 (where a label cannot be above a declaration); in GNU89, mixed declarations and code is allowed, though it's not clear to me from the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Mixed-Declarations.html#Mixed-Declarations) if the C99 rules of lifetime are guaranteed to be honoured.

This code is undefined (in all C standards):

```
void foo(void) {
    int *p = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<2; ++i) {
        int n = 42;
        if(p) { /* (*) */
            printf("%d\n", *p);
        }
        p = &n;
    }
}
```

In the second iteration, `p` refers to the `n` of the first iteration, after its lifetime, though both `n` likely reside at the same storage location, and `42` is outputted. NB, the behaviour is undefined when `(*)` is reached the second time, reading an invalid pointer is undefined, not only the indirection in the `printf` call.